# django TemplateView use pagination and getting only 1 result

Tags: django, python-2.7

i want to make pagination out of **filter_alert** only. 
And i also get only the last result out of **filter_alert**. I will explain more below the code.
This is my code in views.py

```
class TestView(FormView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/main.html'
    context_object_name = 'pages'
    paginate_by = 10
    form_class = DomainsForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        list_tables = Domains.objects.all()
        context['lists'] = list_tables

        tbls_id = list_tables.exclude(status=0).values_list('id', flat=True)
        context['alerts_list'] = Alerts.objects.all()

        data = []

        for row_id in tbls_id:
            cron_info = get_cron_info(row_id)

            data.append(cron_info)
            context['data'] = simplejson.dumps(data)

            tbl = Domains.objects.get(id=row_id)

            t_pages = create_pg("Pages_" + tbl.tablename)

            query_pages = t_pages.objects.all()
            context['pages'] = query_pages

            get_alerts = create_alerts('Links_' + tbl.tablename + '_Alerts')

            filter_alert = get_alerts.objects.all()
            context['all_alerts'] = filter_alert

        return context
```

So in the table *Domains* i have 3 id's, 1 of them has the status=0. I want to get the other 2 id's and pass them through the for loop. But when i pull out the results in the template...i only get the last id.
I am using the **row_id** to get all the id's...i did a print test...and it gives me the 2 id's...but when i want to see all the results of **filter_alerts** it only shows the last id in the template.

I also want to implement the pagination...i usually use this code...but it doesn't work in the *TemplateView*.

```
        all_alerts = get_alerts.objects.all()

        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        paginator = Paginator(all_alerts, 10)
        try:
            details = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            details = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            details = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['all_alerts'] = details
```

I know it's not working because the function **get_context_data** has no request in it. Do i need to create a separate function? Maybe recreate the **get_queryset** function.
I don't know...
Please help. Thank you

***UPDATE***
i used an empty list and append to it...in the template gives me no results

code:

```
        filter_data = []
        for row_id in tbls_id:
            ...
            filter_alert = get_alerts.objects.all()
            filter_data.append(filter_alert)
        print filter_data  # it prints both objects
        context['all_alerts'] = filter_data

        return context
```

in the template.html **all_alerts** doesn't work

Comment: Well you reassign to the context variables in each iteration of the for loop, so naturally they will only have the last values.

Comment: k...so what can i do to fix?

Comment: Don't do that? This is a basic programming issue. Think about exactly what you would like those context variables to contain at the end of the loop.

Comment: all the context variables are good...except the last one...filter_alert

Comment: the one with context['data'] i get both of the results saved....because i m using append....i can't use append on model objects

Comment: You can on a *list* of model objects.

Comment: your talking about creating an empty list and append to it both objects...

Comment: i just said it's not working...it does append to it....how do i see all the results in the template? cause it doesn't show any results in the template...it did append both object's ( i tested it) only if i put [0] or [1] at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

About the pagination part ...found the answer.
it needs to be ***self.request*** not just ***request***.

But i still need the answer for the other problem